# How to create a xib file with a smaller view?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Can I design a View smaller than the complete iPad screen size with UI Builder in xCode 4 ? If so, how ?

I need to design a small View I'm going to use multiple times in the same main UIView.
I would like to design it with UI Builder, and then load it from xib.

But when I create a new xib file, the view size is always the iPad size..
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new view, simply select the "Empty" option, rather than the View option.

You can then drop a UIView on it - the difference being that you can re-size this view via the Size inspector (the little ruler icon) within the utilities pane. (The one on the left.)

Comment: Or just delete the view which was created and add a new one.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 5, change Size to *Freeform*, under Simulated Metrics in the Attributes Inspector

Comment: where is the size? size of what? needs more info

Answer (score 0):

Select view(UIView I must say) then go to Attributes inspector pane and change Size to Freeform by which we can adjust view size now.